# Can I call a variable by constructing it from another variable?

Tags: excel, vba

Hypothetical example, because the full example gets way too complicated:

Let's say I have quantities for three sizes of rolltrailer; Bolster, 40RT and 62RT. I store those quantities in the variables `VarBol`, `Var40RT` and `Var62RT`. The type of rolltrailer would then be selected by another variable, which we'll call RTVar.

Is there any way of constructing a variable to use elsewhere based on that? For instance (and I realize this syntax won't work), something like

```
MsgBox "Quantity is " & ("Var" & RTVar)
```

Or will I end up needing to just a bunch of `IF` statements?

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary` which allows you to store Key/Value pairs, or you could make the variables public members of a class, then use `CallByName` with an instance of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Rory suggested, use a dictionary if you want to access data using strings:

```
Sub test()
    Dim D As Object, s As String

    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    D.Add "Bol", 0 'this is sort of like Dim Bol as Long
    D.Add "40RT", 0
    D.Add "62R", 0

    'can assign like this
    D("Bol") = 5
    D("40RT") = D("Bol") + 7

    'can use like this
    MsgBox D("Bol")

    'or even like this:

    s = "40RT"
    MsgBox D(s)

End Sub
```

Comment: @AndrewPerry You are welcome. Are you still working on that container-packing problem? I remember it from before Christmas but had a much busier Christmas break than I had anticipated and never had time to think much about it.

Comment: I am, yeah - my boss has decided my original plan was needlessly precise, so I've switched it to a volume-based approximation model. That's helped, but there's so much to keep track of and so easy to get lost in the code...

Comment: I can't promise much since I am just starting a new semester, but I've taught Operations Research a few times and have some experience using VBA to solve OR/MS problems using the solver. You can email me at jcoleman@franciscan.edu if you want some feedback on your current approach.

Comment: That's very kind, thanks - I'll see how today's approach works first, but may well take you up on that.